# script only works in IE

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

I have the following JavaScript for show running line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">


//Change script's width (in pixels)
var marqueewidth=800
//Change script's height (in pixels, pertains only to NS)
var marqueeheight=20
//Change script's scroll speed (larger is faster)
var speed=3
//Change script's contents
var marqueecontents='You text here'

if (document.all)
document.write('<marquee scrollAmount='+speed+' style="width:'+marqueewidth+'">'+marqueecontents+'</marquee>')

function regenerate(){
window.location.reload()
}
function regenerate2(){
if (document.layers){
setTimeout("window.onresize=regenerate",450)
intializemarquee()
}
}

function intializemarquee(){
document.cmarquee01.document.cmarquee02.document.write('<nobr>'+marqueecontents+'</nobr>')
document.cmarquee01.document.cmarquee02.document.close()
thelength=document.cmarquee01.document.cmarquee02.document.width
scrollit()
}

function scrollit(){
if (document.cmarquee01.document.cmarquee02.left>=thelength*(-1)){
document.cmarquee01.document.cmarquee02.left-=speed
setTimeout("scrollit()",100)
}
else{
document.cmarquee01.document.cmarquee02.left=marqueewidth
scrollit()
}
}

window.onload=regenerate2
</script>
```

What should I change in script to make it work in FF and Chrome?
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "for show running line"? Do you know where in your code something goes wrong? Please be more specific.

Comment: It should show running string inside the table, which located on the top of the site. It works fine in IE, but in chrome and FF it shows nothing. It doesn't give any errors through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code contains the line `if (document.all)` so the Marquee only gets written to the document in IE.

I've deleted this line and it appears to work in Firefox. I don't have Chrome on this machine to test.

Comment: Plus that "initializemarquee" function looks pretty weird.

Answer (score 2):

1. missing semicolons
2. `document.write()`
3. `document.all`
4. `<marquee>`
5. globals
6. string as `setTimeout` function
7. no indentation

Nostalgia... it's like it's 1998.